# creating a blank option on a drop down list option

Tags: excel, list, drop-down-menu

Within Excel spreadsheet I would like to create a drop-down list with a blank space incase unknown information has to be inputted. I created a list for the most common information that is inputted but once in a blue moon rare information needs to be logged. Since the information is so rare and unknown it’s not possible to include it within the excel drop down box (since it’s unknown at the moment and will only be used once I therefore don’t want to add it within the drop-down list). I have created the list with a blank spot so I can type in the rare information in but when I click the blank information and try to type in the rare information a box pops up and says, this value doesn’t match the date validation restrictions defined for this cell. Is there a way to overcome this in Excel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfZlT.png)

Also, once that problem is solved, I would also like to also have a drop list always present in the column (not just when the field is selected) and I did go to insert and symbols Wingdings 3: 128 but that didn’t work. Maybe it’s because I have included a blank slot in the drop-down list. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an excel label to this post.  Please break up your post into distinct and concise questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think a dropdown list can only have predefined values. If you need other potential values, you would need to add an additional column for that data. Maybe use an option of "Other" in the dropdown and have an extra column for unusual values.